# user.delete().addOnCompleteListener not working in realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have used *anonymous sign in* in my app. So, whenever the user opens the app, the user gets signed in by a new anonymous account. As a result, in spite of having a very few users (around 4 to 5), there are more than 400 signed in accounts in my *Firebase Authentication* section. That's why I thought to delete the user (the anonymous account) when the user closes the app. For this reason, I have used

```
user.delete().addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText( Activity.this, "Deleted Successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText( Activity.this, "Failed" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText( Activity.this, "Failed to delete" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But, the problem is **NO TOAST IS DISPLAYED**. So, what can be causing this problem? I don't know whether the user is being deleted or not. Also, suggest some better way to tackle this problem, if possible.

Comment: *"when the user closes the app"* - so, when is this, exactly?  Android apps don't have an explicit "close" event like desktop apps.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail the timing of this code.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson , I mean to say, I have added this code in onStop(). Please help if you can.

Comment: "That's why I thought to delete the user (the anonymous account) when the user closes the app" I'm not sure I understand the reasoning behind this. What benefit do you get by deleting these anonymous users? What problem would you have by leaving them undeleted?

Comment: @Frank Van Puffelen , I am a beginner in Android App Development and Firebase. All the accounts are visible in my *Authentication* section. So, if all the anonymous accounts remain undeleted, won't I reach the highest limit of users in Spark plan with just 4-5 users? I don't know for sure.

Comment: There is no limit on the number of users that can exist in your Firebase Authentication list. You're likely confusing it with the number of users that can **simultaneously** connect to the Firebase Realtime Database. If only 5 users have installed your app, then the maximum number of simultaneous users will be 5, and the average number of simultaneous users will typically be **much** lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the way that anonymous accounts are meant to be used.  They are expected to persist across app launches so that any per-user data you're storing will continue to be associated with the user as they come and go.  Deleting the account whenever the app is backgrounded is certainly going to cause confusion for both you and the user.

If you want to do something to purge unused accounts, you should have some backend code that uses the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) that periodically [deletes old user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) by whatever criteria you decide that makes that account "old".

Comment: So, your suggestion is that *I should not delete the user accounts*. But in case of *anonymous sign in*, the user gets signed in by a totally different ID. Also, all the previous IDs are stored in the *Users* field under the *Firebase Authentication* section (which I think can never be reused if the user signs out). So, won't it cause a problem if my number of users keep increasing every time a user opens my app? I mean, won't it cause any problem in Spark plan, such as highest limit of users?

Comment: Without seeing the code you're using to manage the account, it's not possible to know if you're doing something wrong.  Anonymous accounts are persistent and will be retained by the app until something signs out the user, the app is uninstalled, or the user clears the app storage.

Comment: Yes, I have added *mAuth.signOut()* in *onStop()*. Because, I thought only upto 100 simultaneous connections are allowed in Spark plan. So, if I don't sign out the users, only the first 100 users who have signed in will be able to use this app. This is my concept. But as I have already mentioned, I am a beginner and I don't know much. So, I maybe wrong. Please suggest me what I should do. Thanks in advance @Doug Stevenson.

Comment: The signout is your problem.  It's effectively forgetting the user account.  Signed in users don't count toward any connection limits, and I think you are misunderstanding what it means to have 100 simultanious connections.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Doug Stevenson